# Copy specific columns based on column headers

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a set columns from one sheet to another.

I have tried this but I want to copy A:D plus other columns such as F, X, V, and so on. Any help would be very useful

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("book1.xlsm").Sheets(1).Columns("A:D")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("book1.xlsm").Sheets(2).Columns("A:D")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to copy them one after the other (and not column "F" of sheet1 in column "F" of sheet2, etc.)

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()

Dim sourceColumn As Range

With Sheets(1)
    Set sourceColumn = Union(.Columns("A:D"), .Columns("F"), .Columns("X"), .Columns("V"))
End With

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know the specific columns you want to copy, it can be done more directly:

```
    Sheets(1).Range("A:D,F:F,X:X,V:V").Copy Sheets(2).Range("A1")
```